# Slickgrid keypress lost while tabbing between cells

Tags: slickgrid

Using slickgrid v2.1 with autoEdit=true, if you press TAB and, while TAB is still pressed, you press another character, this character is lost.

I can reproduce in the [editing sample](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html) :

1. Set Auto-edit to ON
2. Go into a 'Duration' cell
3. Press TAB, keep it pressed
4. Press a number (ex: 5) before TAB start repeating
5. The value '5' will not be set in the '% Complete' cell

This is with IE10. Chrome does not have this problem.

We have some users that do fast data input, and this problem occurs very frequently. This is a major irritant as the users are not aware the app is discarding some keystroke, and others problems arise later on because of the invalid data.

Any clue how could we solve this using IE10 ?